# incompatible array delphi7

Tags: arrays, delphi-7

I have an array of bytes and another array of array of bytes.

```
type
 TByteArray = array of byte;
 TArraykearray = array of array of byte;

function TFRTConnection1.GetBytes(value: integer): TBytearray;
begin
  SetLength(Result, SizeOf(value));
  Move(value, Result[0], SizeOf(value));
end;

Function TFRTConnection1.addco(point: TPoint) : Tarraykearray;
var
 result1 : Tarraykearray;
begin
 setLength(Result1,10);
 Result1[0] := getBytes(1);
 Result1[1] := 1;
 ....
 Result := result1;
end;
```

When i use Result1[0] := getBytes(1); i get incompatible types error. 
I do not want to make TArraykearray as array of Tbytearray because that is an array of array on the server side of the application for which I do not have access to.

Is there another possibility?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot assign a `TByteArray` to an `array of byte`, the compiler treats them as separate types even though internally they are compatible.  You need to change `TArraykearray` to use `TByteArray` instead:

```
type
  TByteArray = array of byte;
  TArraykearray = array of TByteArray;
```

Or else you will have to use a type-cast when assigning the array:

```
Function TFRTConnection1.addco(point: TPoint) : Tarraykearray;
type
  PByteArray = ^TByteArray;
var
  Result1 : TArraykearray;
begin
  SetLength(Result1,10);
  PByteArray(@Result1[0])^ := getBytes(1);
  ....
end;
```

BTW: `Result1[1] := 1;` will not compile either, as you cannot assign a single integer to an array.